# Add ones UIScrollView Gesture recognisers to another UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

i have a point in my app where I remove one scrollview and add another. I want the same gestures in my previous scroll view to be present in the new one.
I have tried:

```
            scrollView.gestureRecognizers = self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers;
```

But it just gave me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249402/can-i-pass-a-pinch-gesture-recognizer-to-a-scrollview-to-have-it-zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the gesture recognizer with the new target. You can't just copy it like this.

```
    UIGestureRecognizer *newGestureRecognizer = [UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:newScrollView action:@selector(yourAction);
```

Comment: I was thinking about reusing those guys.

Comment: @DevFly After some testing, scrollView.gestureRecognizers is an NSArray of various UIGestureRecognizers. You should get the one that interest you in the list and add you new scrollview as one of its targets : - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action

Comment: That's great! Gonna try it now.